# Groovy on Android Skipped frames! doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, groovy, dagger

I am playing around with Groovy on Android. When I change a constructor (object) from Java to Groovy, I got skip-frame issue (*doing too much work on its main thread*).

Here's my Dagger provide method.

```
@Provides
public IXxx provideXxx() {
    return new XxxGroovy(mApp); // Groovy -> skipped frames
    //return new XxxJava(mApp); // Java -> no problem
}
```

The constructor is pretty much nothing and they are the same in both versions:

```
XxxGroovy(Application app) {
    mApp = app
}
```

I am new to Groovy and have no idea what causes the issue. Could anybody give me some pointers? Thanks

Comment: Same here. Android Studio memory manager shows the app demanding a lot of ram to startup, I assume it's the groovy runtime loading and it's a major slowdown. Didn't find any solution yet, just add @CompileStatic to all your Groovy classes and let's keep polling Champeau's website for updates.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. I'll try @CompileStatic thanks!!